# How to specify the endiannes directly in the numpy datatype for a 16bit unsigned integer?

Tags: python, numpy

I would think this is a simple question but I haven't found the answer so far.

I work with fairly large (~2 GB) binary data images. I load them into python with the line

```
data = np.memmap(filename, dtype=np.dtype('uint16'), mode='r').byteswap()
```

For large files this can take several seconds. Anyway, I notice that the same line but without the byteswapping takes only an instant.

So the question is this: is there a way to specify the Byte order directly in the datatype so I don't need to do the byteswap afterwards? According to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html,

> A data type object (...) describes the following aspects of the data:
>   (...) 3. Byte order of the data (little-endian or big-endian) (...)

How do I do this for a 16-bit unsigned integer? Things like `np.dtype('>uint16')` haven't worked for me, they give me a `TypeError: data type ">uint16" not understood` error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

specify dtype as `>H` ([Numeric typecodes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types)) or `>u2` ([Array-protocol type strings](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html#python-side)):

```
np.memmap('test.bin', dtype=np.dtype('>u2'), mode='r')
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Anyway, I'd like to understand why `u2` is the same as `uint16`, I haven't found that in your links, explainations there are a little cumbersome for me.

Comment: @user2834480, The text in the second link says: `... and an integer providing the number of bytes the type uses`.  `2` in `u2` means 2 bytes, while `16` in `uint16` means 16 bits (2 bytes == 16 bits)